# standard deviation help

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, mean

A tire manufacturer believes that the tread-life of its snow tires can be described by a normal model with a mean of 32 thousand miles and standard deviation of 2.5 thousand miles. Based on this information answer the following questions

1. What fraction of these tires can be expected to last less than 30 thousand miles
2. What fraction of these tires can be expected to last between 30-35 thousand miles
3. In planning a marketing strategy, a local tire dealer wants to offer a refund to any customer whose tires fail to last a certain number of miles. However, the dealer does not want to take too big a risk. If the dealer is willing to give refunds to no more tan 4% of customers, for what mileage can he guarantee these tires to last?

I need to know the steps in reaching these answers please!

Comment: Added the self-study tag because this smells of homework.

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @Erin, but we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: For more examples of these calculations, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+probability).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different approaches that you could use, which you should use depends on what your teacher/textbook uses.

This may be a matter of using the above information and putting it into the formula to compute a z-score, then looking up that value on the Normal table (or looking up the value on the normal table to find the z-score and converting back for the last one).

Or if using a computer then you need to find the right function for your software (`pnorm` and `qnorm` for R, but different for other packages) and plug all the correct values in the correct places and it will give the answer.

In all cases it is good to start by drawing a picture (the normal curve) and labeling the mean and the point of interest.  This can help to make sure that you use the table/function correctly and as a sanity check for any mistakes (if the picture suggests an answer less than 0.5 and the answer you compute is greater than 0.5 then double check everything).

We need to know what you have tried so far and which approach your class is expecting you to use to be of any more help.